# What causes the cart module to not show up on the front-office?

Tags: module, themes, prestashop, smarty

Recently I was doing some integrations on a non-standard/non-official prestashop 1.6 theme.

I found out after some manipulation on the Back-Office that the cart module doesn't appear on the Front-Office.
The cart module is enabled and is hooked to the displayNav and displayTop hooks. 
It seems that cart module doesn't render any of its view code even when the "Disable module ovverides" is disabled.

The last and the only thing I've manipulated on the BO config is activating and then deactivating the "Force update friendly url".

Note that the current theme in based on an old theme and was made by an intern that didn't respect the official doc at all. What I mean by that is that you can find inline CSS and Javascript isnide a tpl file with no repsect of the smarty template engine syntax.

The current theme doesn't support many of the hooks that the default and basic prestashop theme offers.

I envisionned the following solution :

- Read the 1.6 PS doc and make corrections on the theme. If the number of bugs, problems and mis-uses is not huge.
- Rewrite the theme from groung zero in the worst case

Comment: was the cart block showing in front before and suddenly disappered ?

Answer (score 0):

After one day of lookin up answers on the web I found out that the catalog mode was off which makes the cart block disapears on the front-office.